# Why do I receive a 'Bad Request' error when adding a meetingRegistrant via the MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We have been trying to add a registrant to a meeting using the MS Graph API. The meeting was created in Teams as a Webinar.

We have managed to authenticate and get the meeting ID, but we cannot add the registrant.

The error message in the API is very uninformative as well. If we make an obvious mistake, like omit a required field, we get a reasonable error message. But as soon as we put together what looks like a correct request, we just get the below message.

Can anybody see any obvious issues with our request? The request details are below:

Method: POST
URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/659fc6aa-615f-4cfc-8646-e8e4c7ad8c67/onlineMeetings/MSo2NTlmYzZhYS02MTVmLTRjZmMtODY0Ni1lOGU0YzdhZDhjNjcqMCoqMTk6bWVldGluZ19PR0prWTJGa1pqRXRaV1ZsTkMwME1XTXlMVGc0TldNdE9UQXhPVFppWVRjNE1UUmhAdGhyZWFkLnYy/registration/registrants

BODY:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.meetingRegistrant",
  "firstName": "firstname",
  "lastName": "lastname",
  "email": "email address removed for privacy reasons"
}
```

HEADERS:

Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}
Content-Type: application/json

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Bad Request",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-02-28T16:31:53",
            "request-id": "7767a8a2-770b-458d-9492-ab46a16f6c9b",
            "client-request-id": "7767a8a2-770b-458d-9492-ab46a16f6c9b"
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: We also tried to repro this issue by creating a meeting in MS teams as webinar. However, while adding a meetingRegistrant via the MS Graph API, received a 'Bad Request' error.

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same and engineering team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any further update. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Prasad-MSFT, thanks! Do you know if regular Teams meetings have the same issue or if this is just effecting webinars?

Comment: We tested this with webinar only.

Comment: Is this issue still reproable? We got latest update from engineering team that, "the meeting registrant Graph API only supports "webinar v1" _(you can no longer create a webinar v1 in Teams; you can only create them from Graph)_, while the webinar created in Teams is now "webinar v2". For "webinar v2" you can reference the virtual event webinar Graph APIs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/virtualeventwebinar?view=graph-rest-beta